# Picocli: How can I decouple @Options attributes from a command class?

Tags: java, spring-boot, picocli

I want my app to adhere to the SOLID principles. Using picocli has been a godsend, but annotated @Option attributes are coupled to their respective classes. In my case I want it to be possible to simply put the options into their own classes.

So what I mean is, instead of having to do this:

```
@Command(name = "finderapp")
class FindSomethingCommand implements Callable<Integer> {

    @Option(names = {"-u", "--username"}, description = "Search for this name")
    String userName;

    @Option(names = {"-py", "--productionyear"}, description = "Search by 
    production year")
    String productionYear;

    @Option(names = {"-p", "--price"}, description = "Search for by price")
    String price;

    public Integer call() throws Exception {
        if (userName != null) {
           //do stuff with userName
        }
        if (productionYear!= null) {
           //do stuff with productionYear
        }
        if (price!= null) {
           //do stuff with price
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I want it do be something like this:

```
@Command(name = "finderapp")
class FindSomethingCommand implements Callable<Integer> {

    private List<MyOption> myOptions;

    public static void addOption(MyOption myoption) {
       myOptions.add(myOption);
    }

    public Integer call() {
        myOptions.stream().forEach(o -> o.executeCall());
        return 0;
    }
}

// @OptionOfCommand annotation does not exist, this is just an example of how it could be done
@OptionOfCommand(FindSomethingCommand.class) 
public class UserNameOption implements MyOption {

   @Option(names = {"-u", "--username"}, description = "Search for this name")
    String userName;

   @Override
   public void executeCall() {
      //do something with userName
   }

}


public interface MyOption {

   public void executeCall();

}
```

In the terminal it then should look like this:

```
$finderapp -u JohnDoe -p 200 -py 2022
```

As you can see the problem is adding more options in the future for one command will not adhere to the SOLID principles. It should be possible to just ad a MyOption class with a new option and what it should do when called. Ultimately, if new search parameters are added there will be a long disgusting if-chain that has to be manually updated.

I would really appreciate it if anyone could help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `@Mixin` annotation.

```java
@Command(name = "finderapp")
class FindSomethingCommand implements Callable<Integer> {

    @Mixin
    private UserNameOption userNameOption;

    @Mixin
    private ProductionYearOption productionYearOption;

    @Mixin
    private PriceOption priceOption;

    public Integer call() {
        userNameOption.executeCall();
        productionYearOption.executeCall();
        priceOption.executeCall();
        return 0;
    }
}

@Command(name = "finderapp")
class UserNameOption implements MyOption {

   @Option(names = {"-u", "--username"}, description = "Search for this name")
    String userName;

   @Override
   public void executeCall() {
      //do something with userName
   }

}

@Command(name = "finderapp")
class ProductionYearOption implements MyOption {

   @Option(names = {"-py", "--productionyear"}, description = "Search by production year")
    String productionYear;

   @Override
   public void executeCall() {
      //do something with productionYear
   }

}

@Command(name = "finderapp")
class PriceOption implements MyOption {

   @Option(names = {"-p", "--price"}, description = "Search for by price")
    String price;

   @Override
   public void executeCall() {
      //do something with price
   }

}
```

Comment: I did not know that, thank you. This is pretty close to what I am looking for.

Unfortunately, the Option classes still need to be declared in the command. A perfect solution in my mind would be if the command class can collect all of its Option classes into a list and then just iterate through the list, calling all the executeCall() methods. That way the FindSomethingCommand class would never have to be touched again, but is open for extension.